# In Snowflake warehouse_load_history table what exactly AVG_RUNNING column means?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

In `warehouse_load_history` table the column `AVG_RUNNING`. Does it calculate both the metadata queries and normal queries? I want to know whether this column is calculating the running avg queries of `CREDITS_USED_CLOUD_SERVICES` or `CREDITS_USED_COMPUTE` or Both?